# Telerik MVC Grid - Enable editing clientside

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I know this is a rather specific question - but I wasn't able to find any help in the [Telerik MVC Grid documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnEdit).

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a way to trigger a grid into "edit mode" via a client-side event. I was having issues with the toolbar and thought this might be possible through jQuery / JavaScript.

```
        $('#addName').click(function () {

            var grid = $("#NamesGrid").data("tGrid");

            //Enable Editing here?

            return grid;

        });
```

I am using server-side binding - so hitting a Controller action wouldn't really be an issue, if I had to do a `.post` or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of exploring through source - you can accomplish this by adding the following:

```
 $('#addName').click(function () 
 {
      window.location = "[ControllerAction]?[NamesGrid]-mode=insert";
 });
```

Obviously this example was for a grid inside of a popup window - but hopefully this could help others if they ran into similar issues.